# Query on object lock on an AS400 physical file

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

When an object lock happens on an AS400 physical file, is there any possibility to know on which record/data the record lock has happened?

Comment: Are you just wanting to see what's locked now?  Or are you trying to programmatically see what lock caused a "record in use"  exception?

Comment: did you try working with the job, viewing open files and seeing what record it's on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DSPRCDLCK (Display Record Locks) command to view the record locks from command line.

If you need to access this info in the program, You could try using 'RECORD_LOCK_INFO' (RCD_LOCK) view in QSYS2 library.